# C# UWP AudioDeviceInputNode AccessDenied

Tags: c#, uwp

I try create AudioDeviceInputNode, but in result returns AccessDenied

```
public async Task CreateDeviceInputNode()
{
    var result = await audioGraph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(MediaCategory.Media);

    if (result.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success) //Status == AcessDenied
    {
        throw new Exception(result.Status.ToString());
    }

    deviceInputNode = result.DeviceInputNode;
}
```

In capabilites Microphone checked, any code with deivce input returns AccessDenied, even from sdk samples. What could be the problem?

[capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZd7P.png)

Comment: Have you tried with [AudioGraph sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation)? Does it have the same problem?

Comment: @Scavenger, yes i tried it, same problem, after sample i try this in new project, but access denied, my microphone connected

Comment: That's strange. This sample works well in my machine. Have you tried with other device? Maybe the problem is related to your test device.

Comment: Enable access to the microphone in the project's app manifest?

Answer (score 0):

check out Settings -> Privacy -> microphone.

might be disabled microphone to your application.